# Eliminar porción de palabra en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, web

tengo una duda. Deseo eliminar una porción de una palabra usando PHP. Por ejemplo:
PALABRA: ","0,2
Deseo que quede solo 0,2 sin que se elimine la , de en medio del número decimal.

Comment: Buenas, Elisa, ¿quieres eliminar el primer caracter o la primera coma sabiendo que siempre hay dos comas? ¿Cuál es la porción que quieres eliminar y donde se espera que esté? ¿Y qué has intentado hasta ahora para conseguirlo?

Comment: Los primeros caracteres para que solo quede el 0,2 ya que siempre sale el '","0,2'

Comment: Hacen falta detalles, ¿Siempre tienes este formato?: `""entero[,][decimal]`?. ¿La cadena es de una línea o puede ser multilinea? ¿Pueden haber más ocurrencias en la cadena, y de ser así qué quieres hacer con todas?

Comment: El formato es: comilla coma comilla decimal, deseándose suprimir y que quede solo el decimal. La palabra resultante es de un array en sí, que al dividirse  mediante explode("-"; ...) queda de esa forma todos los resultados

Comment: Si siempre tiene ese formato, yo lo haría así:
$palabra = '","0,2';
$resultado = str_replace('","', '', $palabra);
echo $resultado;

Comment: Gracias, funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo tu [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/604462/eliminar-porci%C3%B3n-de-palabra-en-php#comment1067093_604462):

> ... La palabra resultante es de un array en sí, que al dividirse mediante `explode("-"; ...)` queda de esa forma todos los resultados

Podrías entonces cambiar el carácter del `explode`, es decir,  en lugar de `-`, pondrías **`","`**, así, en la posición `1` del array resultante tendrías el valor que requieres.

Por ejemplo:

```
$str = 'loQueSea-","0,2'; 
$arr=explode('","',$str);
echo $arr[1]; // 0,2
```

---

```
$str = 'Antes del separador-","0,35'; 
$arr=explode('","',$str);
echo $arr[1]; // 0,35
```